# How to find out the locations of entry and exit from a maze picture

Tags: python, image-processing, maze, opencv

Just wondering is it possible to find out the entry and exit points of a maze in a picture?

I have highlighted the 2 points with red and blue for explaining purpose, but they do not exist in the original picture, so please don't count on them.

The locations of the entry and exit can be vary, e.g. they could be in the middle of an edge, but not limited to the locations which are the corner or the middle.

I notice that there are 2 black arrows pointing to the 2 locations, but how to locate the 2 locations without the help of these 2 arrows?

[image]

### Update 1

I should upload the processed image here:

[image]

After applied some image processing procedures, I have gotten the extracted maze. But this is not what I am asking, let's get back to the topic and the extracted maze image should be the starting point for this question.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: The answer to your questions "Is ___ possible?" is yes (with a lot of caveats hard to explain). But it looks like your code just calls Canny edge detection and then there's no attempt to address the problem. Do your best to solve the problem. Google maze-solving algorithms. Try to solve a MUCH simpler problem first, then work your way up.

Comment: hi @Prune I'm not asking for a exactly piece of code to solve this problem. All I need to know is the thought of how to solving this problem, I can then implement it if possible.

Comment: @Prune there are differences between 1. asking for a piece of code which solves the problem and 2. asking for a thought/idea to solve the problem. You can have an idea to solve this problem but being lazy so come here to ask for code, that's what is discouraged. But if I do not event know whether this is possible, or do not know how to do this, then I cannot show you my honest attempt. I am more than happy to show my code once I have an idea about how to solve this problem.

Comment: hi @Rethunk I have had my code to solve maze problem, that's not what I am asking. I am asking for a thought/ an idea about how to find out the 2 points. Without an idea, I cannot really show any piece of code. I hope you could understand my point. thanks

Comment: I feel that your question(s) is (are) way too broad for this platform. You have to divide even further the problem, but as it is presented now, it is very complex and has many constraints. Let’s try to divide the problem into smaller pieces. Suppose you locate the maze from everything in the frame. Then, you have to segment it to obtain a mask. The perspective is a little bit distorted, perhaps it should be rectified.

Comment: Now, once you have the maze isolated, try to locate the start/exit points. One possible step towards this is maybe isolate the outer “[frame](https://i.imgur.com/7dtzKKm.png)” of it and look for discontinuities. Now, you say that the algorithm(s) should handle various types of mazes (that are not provided) so I don’t know if even this proposal will satisfy your needs. I feel that the optimal solution in this case should escalate to deep learning to at least locate the maze in the frame.

Comment: In short, this is not trivial and, as it is now, I think the request is out of the scope of this platform. Maybe someone kind enough can invest a (no negligible) amount of time and actually try and fulfill it, but maybe you'd have better luck if you define a smaller problem towards a more general solution.

Comment: I didn't say you were asking for code.  However, whether you're asking for code or asking for someone to lead you through a solution path, the question is out of scope.  Again, please see the posting guidelines.  You need to search for appropriate solutions before posting here.  I've seen other postings for visual processing of mazes, and I believe that a couple of those had found solutions with browser research.

Comment: @Prune sure, I have updated my question.

Comment: hi @eldesgraciado thanks for your suggestion, I should use the extracted maze image here. I have uploaded it please see my update 1. Don't worry about extracting the maze from the image, that part has been done. Now we have the binary value image(black and white), we can focus on locating the start and end points.

Comment: I think this is too broad also. It looks like it has garnered an answer, but the piece of code in the question makes things confusing, since it lacks any context. I might have left the question standing without that. If you would like to reopen the question, could you edit it to explain what the code does, and why you are showing it?

Comment: @halfer sure. I have updated the question. This is just asking for automatically detecting the entry points of a maze.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started with your extracted maze image.
The first thing to do is to find the four corners of the maze. We can find them by just looking for the four most extreme (closest to the corner of the image) points.
We can connect up these four corners to make a (sort of) rectangle that encloses our maze.

[image]

The idea is to find the longest line of non-occupied (white) points that is perpendicular to the edges of our rectangle. To simplify the math for this we can rectify the image since we know the four corners.

Running through the edges and "raycasting" until we hit a wall, here are some graphs of the length of each line found along each edge.

Top Edge

[image]

Left Edge

[image]

Bottom Edge

[image]

Right Edge

[image]

Now we can just find the longest line for each edge, take the highest two, and those are our entrances to the maze.

[image]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# tuplifies a point for opencv
def tup(p):
    return (int(p[0]), int(p[1]));

# load image
img = cv2.imread("maze.png");

# resize
scale = 0.5;
h, w = img.shape[:2];
h = int(h*scale);
w = int(w*scale);
img = cv2.resize(img, (w,h));
copy = np.copy(img);

# mask image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
mask = cv2.inRange(gray, 100, 255);

# find corners
corners = [[[0,0], 0] for a in range(4)];
for y in range(h):
    # progress check
    print(str(y) + " of " + str(h));
    for x in range(w):
        # check pixel
        if mask[y][x] == 0:
            # scores
            scores = [];
            scores.append((h - y) + (w - x)); # top-left
            scores.append((h - y) + x); # top-right
            scores.append(y + x); # bottom-right
            scores.append(y + (w - x)); # bottom-left
            
            # check corners
            for a in range(len(scores)):
                if scores[a] > corners[a][1]:
                    corners[a][1] = scores[a];
                    corners[a][0] = [x, y];

# draw connecting lines
for a in range(len(corners)):
    prev = corners[a-1][0];
    curr = corners[a][0];
    cv2.line(img, tup(prev), tup(curr), (0,200,0), 2);

# draw corners
for corner in corners:
    cv2.circle(img, tup(corner[0]), 4, (255,255,0), -1);

# re-orient to make the math easier
rectify = np.array([[0,0], [w,0], [w,h], [0,h]]);
numped_corners = [corner[0] for corner in corners];
numped_corners = np.array(numped_corners);
hmat, _ = cv2.findHomography(numped_corners, rectify);
rect = cv2.warpPerspective(copy, hmat, (w,h));

# redo mask
gray = cv2.cvtColor(rect, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
mask = cv2.inRange(gray, 100, 255); 

# dilate
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8);
mask = cv2.erode(mask, kernel, iterations = 5);

# find entrances
top = []; # [score, point]
# top side
for x in range(w):
    y = 0;
    while mask[y][x] == 255:
        y += 1;
    top.append([y, [x,0]]);
# left side
left = [];
for y in range(h):
    x = 0;
    while mask[y][x] == 255:
        x += 1;
    left.append([x, [0,y]]);
# bottom side
bottom = [];
for x in range(w):
    y = h-1;
    while mask[y][x] == 255:
        y -= 1;
    bottom.append([(h - y) - 1, [x, h-1]]);
# right side
right = [];
for y in range(h):
    x = w-1;
    while mask[y][x] == 255:
        x -= 1;
    right.append([(w - x) - 1, [w-1,y]]);

# combine
scores = [top, left, bottom, right];

# plot
for side in scores:
    fig = plt.figure();
    ax = plt.axes();
    y = [score[0] for score in side];
    x = [a for a in range(len(y))];
    ax.plot(x, y);
    plt.show();

# get the top score for each side
highscores = []; # [score, [x, y]];
for side in scores:
    top_score = -1;
    top_point = [-1, -1];
    for score in side:
        if score[0] > top_score:
            top_score = score[0];
            top_point = score[1];
    highscores.append([top_score, top_point]);

# get the top two (assuming that there are two entrances to the maze)
one = [0, [0,0]];
two = [0, [0,0]];
for side in highscores:
    if side[0] > one[0]:
        two = one[:];
        one = side[:];
    elif side[0] > two[0]:
        two = side[:];

# draw the entrances
cv2.circle(rect, tup(one[1]), 5, (0,0,255), -1);
cv2.circle(rect, tup(two[1]), 5, (0,0,255), -1);

# show
cv2.imshow("Image", img);
cv2.imshow("Rect", rect);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```

Comment: Thanks @IanChu! Gosh, I like your fabulous idea! Initially, I was thinking of something I recalled from my university time, "overflow". It mimics water overflows where no blocking objects. But your idea is better! I spent the whole morning to understand your code, search related concepts, the next time when I looked at my watch, it's 4 hours passed! Such a good 4 hours intensive learning! Btw, the `raycasting` is very vivid word! Overall, thank you for your help and the thoughts and code really enlighten me!

Comment: @halfer oh right. I just realized I pasted into the OneDrive link for my maze photos. I will delete them. thanks for spotting it.